# Use covering number to get uniform concentration from pointwise concentration

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, learning-theory

Let $\Theta$ be a subset of a metric space. Suppose $(X_\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta}$ is a random process on $\Theta$ which is $L$-Lipschitz and with the property that there exists constants $A, B>0$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ and $\theta \in \Theta$, it holds that $P(X_\theta \ge \epsilon) \le A\exp(-B\epsilon^2)$.

## Question

- What upper bounds can be obtained on $P(\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} X_\theta \ge \epsilon)$ in terms of the Lipschitz constant $L$, and the covering number of $\Theta$ ?
- In case the conditions are not sufficient, what can be added in order to obtain any interesting answers ?

Comment: You need some Lipschitz (or other smoothness property) on $X_\theta$ in $\theta$.

Comment: OK, I see. I just added the condition to the question. Thanks. This is so as to be able to bound the covering number of $\{X_\theta | \theta \in \Theta\}$ in terms of that of $\Theta$, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for all $\theta \in\Theta$ we have $P(X_\theta\ge\epsilon)\le
A\exp(-B\epsilon^2)$ and $\Theta$ has $\epsilon$-packing number $M(\epsilon)$ and additionally $X_\theta$ is $L$-Lipschitz in $\theta$, then
$$P(\sup_{\theta\in\Theta} X_\theta>\epsilon(L+1))
\le AM(\epsilon)\exp(-B\epsilon^2)
.$$

Comment: Great. Thanks. Where I can find a proof of this / similar claims ?

Comment: It's immediate from the Lipschitz property and union bound. Try it as an exercise, and if you still need help, I'll fill in the details.

Comment: OK, thanks for the the hint. See the proof below. I need to stop being lazy...

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is just a detailed version of Aryeh's answer.

So, let $\mathcal C_\epsilon$ be $\epsilon/2$-cover for $\Theta$ of minimal cardinality $N(\Theta;\epsilon/2)$. Let $C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon$ and $\theta_0 \in C$. Then because the distance between any two points in $C$ is at most $\epsilon$, one has
$$
\sup_{\theta \in C} X_\theta = X_{\theta_0} + \sup_{\theta \in C}\;(X_\theta-X_{\theta_0}) \le X_{\theta_0} + \epsilon L,
$$
and so

> $P(\sup_{\theta \in C} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L+1)) \le P(X_{\theta_0} \ge \epsilon) \le A\exp(-B\epsilon^2)$.

On the other hand,

$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L + 1) \implies \exists \theta \in \Theta | X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L + 1) \implies \exists C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon | \sup_{\theta \in C} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L+1),
$$
and so applying the union bound on the finite cover $\mathcal C_\epsilon$, one gets

$$
\begin{split}
P\left(\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L + 1)\right) &\le P\left(\bigsqcup_{C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon}\left\{\sup_{\theta \in C} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L+1)\right\} \right) \\
&\le \sum_{C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon}P\left(\sup_{\theta \in C} X_\theta \ge \epsilon(L+1)\right)\\
&\le AN(\Theta;\epsilon/2)\exp(-B\epsilon^2).
\end{split}
$$
Thus, we have the concentration inequality

> $$P\left(\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} X_\theta \ge \epsilon\right) \le AN(\Theta;\epsilon/2)\exp\left(-\frac{B\epsilon^2}{L+1}\right)
> $$

Comment: It's not true that the distance of any two points in $C$ is at most $\epsilon$.

Comment: That's a typo / thinko. I actually meant  $2\epsilon$. Thanks.

Comment: Actually $\mathcal{C}_\epsilon$ is a cover (of "type" set) and $C\in \mathcal{C}_\epsilon$ is a point -- so we should be talking about the distance between any two points in $\mathcal{C}_\epsilon$. The latter could be large -- roughly as large as the diameter of $\Theta$.

Comment: I don't get that. I'm not interested by the distance about two points in $C_\epsilon$ (which wouldn't make much sense, since there is no geometry on $\mathcal C_\epsilon$, just a set of things...). I'm interested in the distance between two points $x$ and $y$ with $x, y \in C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon \subseteq \mathcal 2^\Theta$, and this can certainly be talked about, since $C$ is a subset of the metric space $\Theta$. No ?

Comment: What is the "type" of $\mathcal{C}_\epsilon$? Is it a subset of $\Theta$?

Comment: $\mathcal C_\epsilon$ is a **collection of subsets** of $\Theta$. Each element / point $C$ of $\mathcal C_\epsilon$ is a **subset** of $\Theta$.

Comment: That's not the standard definition of $\epsilon$-cover.

Comment: OK, i just checked and it seems this is indeed not how people usually define it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number#Definition. Here is my working definition: Given $\epsilon \ge 0$, a collection $C_\epsilon$ of subsets of $\Theta$ is said to be an $\epsilon$-cover for $\Theta$ if the diameter of each $C \in \mathcal C_\epsilon$ is at most $2\epsilon$ and $\Theta \subseteq \bigsqcup_{C \in C_\epsilon} C $. You will agree with me that this is essentially equivalent to the standard one ;)